# Writing text all time hidden when write something on EditText in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext

My images. such as

[image]

when i write something then show image like

[image]

But i want write something and show that also.

My Codes :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff" >

    <!-- Header aligned to top -->

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >


    <include
        android:id="@+id/header"
        layout="@layout/header" >
    </include>

    <!-- Footer aligned to bottom -->


    <!-- Content below header and above footer -->

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/content"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/locationLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Ubicación"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

                <Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/locationSpinner"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/deprtmentLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/locationLayout"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Departamento"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

                <Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/departmentSpinner"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/folderpathLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/deprtmentLayout"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Carpeta"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

                <Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/folderSpinner"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/locatioRnLayoutT"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/folderpathLayout"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:gravity="center|end"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="left"
                    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                    android:text="comentario"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/etComments"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="top|left"
                    android:hint="escribir comentario aquí"
                    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                    android:lines="8"
                    android:maxLines="10"
                    android:minLines="4"
                    android:scrollbars="vertical" >

                    <requestFocus />
                </EditText>
            </LinearLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/footer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="#0c95d4" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:gravity="center" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/backImageView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/img_selector"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:onClick="doActions"
                android:src="@drawable/back_black" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="1" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="1" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/reportOk"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/img_selector"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:onClick="doActions"
                android:src="@drawable/right_button_white" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="1" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="1" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/img_selector"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:onClick="doActions" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

And header.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="5" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvHeader"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/layout"
                android:layout_weight="4"
                android:paddingLeft="8dp"
                android:text="Fixed Header"
                android:textColor="#33b5e5"
                android:textSize="12sp" />

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/layout"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/iHome"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/img_selector"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:onClick="goToHome"
                    android:src="@drawable/home_black" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/ilogout"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/iHome"
                    android:background="@drawable/img_selector"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:onClick="logoutAction"
                    android:paddingRight="8dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/logout_black" />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="3dip"
            android:background="#33b5e5" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

when i write something on comment field then show pop-up windows for writing input then i don't show any text what i do write on EditText. How to show input field when i write some thing. please help me.

Comment: I want to see what i do write on EditText when i write somethings.

Comment: So nothing is inputted when you write to the edittext?

Comment: try setting another `textColor`, maybe you are writing white on white.

Comment: can anybody help me how to show my EditText field when i write somethings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set appropriate [`windowSoftInputMode`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#wsoft) for your `activity` in the manifest. `adjustPan` is probably what you're looking for there.